# Difficulty Restoring Database in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Unfortunately, I am experiencing a problem restoring a database on my laptop.

This is the error message that is being displayed in SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio:

[image]

How can I solve this problem please?

**Update**

It seems that I have to update my SQL Server 2008 R2 to Service Pack 2.  Am I correct?  I tried using the link from Microsoft however it requires around 5 hours to download because of the slow download speed (my internet reaches up to 1.2 MB/s download speed so the problem is not on my part).

Is there an alternative place from where I can download SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2?

Comment: Are you able to install the same SQL version on your laptop?

Comment: I'm trying to download Service Pack 2 for SQL Server 2008 R2 but the download speed is extremely slow.  I am getting around 20 KB/s.  Do you now of some place else where I can download SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2 apart from Microsoft's website?

Comment: This is the link I am using: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30437

Comment: Downloads from MS are usually fast, it might be your connection? Either way, you will need this update so it might just need to be a patient wait.

Comment: I hope that it works afterwards.  I have 4 hours 45 minutes more to wait :s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are running `SQL Server 2008` and your database backup is from `SQL Server 2008 **R2**`. That is what I infer from above screen shot. It is not about service packs but about SQL Server releases which is not backward incompatible. Refer [this blog](http://sqlserverversions.blogspot.in/) to get to know versions of SQL Server. You will have to upgrade your server.

To know what is your SQL Server version, you can use `Select @@version`.

[Update] - Alternatively, you can generate SQL Server Scripts and data which is compatible with SQL Server 2008. If your database is not huge, this can work and it will be quick.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 and managed to restore the back-ups.